# Can not Insert data into MySQL from PHP form

Tags: php, html, mysql

After I fill up the PHP form, the data is not showing in mysql. What is wrong with my code and how can i fix it?

These are all my codes. Please help me I am still a beginner in php. I tried searching my error in other websites however it is not working.

This is the code for the form
**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- C R E A T E  D A T A -->
  <form class="" action="createdatatry.php" method="post">
    <h3>ENTER THE FOLLOWING SUPPLIER INFORMATION:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_Name" placeholder="Enter Supplier Name" required/>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_Contact" placeholder="Enter Contact No." required/>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_StreetNo" placeholder="Enter Street No." required/>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_Province" placeholder="Enter Province" required/>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_PostalCode" placeholder="Enter Postal Code" required/>
    <input type="text" name="Supplier_Country" placeholder="Enter Country" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="CREATE">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for the mysql connection
**database.php**

```
<?php
    
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'sourcingdb';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Error Unable to connect to MySQL server <br>";
    echo "Message: ".mysqli_connect_error()."<br>";
} 


?>
```

This is the code in creating/ inserting data into mysql
**createdatatry.php**

```
<?php

require('./database.php');

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $Supplier_Name = $_POST['Supplier_Name'];
    $Supplier_Contact = $_POST['Supplier_Contact'];
    $Supplier_StreetNo = $_POST['Supplier_StreetNo'];
    $Supplier_Prov = $_POST['Supplier_Prov'];
    $Supplier_PostalCode = $_POST['Supplier_PostalCode'];
    $Supplier_Country = $_POST['Supplier_Country'];

    $queryCreate = "INSERT INTO supplierinfo (`Supplier_Name`, `Supplier_Contact`, `Supplier_StreetNo`, `Supplier_Province`, `Supplier_PostalCode`, `Supplier_Country`) VALUES ('$Supplier_name', '$Supplier_Contact', '$Supplier_StreetNo', '$Supplier_Prov', '$Supplier_PostalCode', '$Supplier_ountry')";
    $sqlCreate = mysqli_query($connection, $queryCreate);

    echo '<script>alert("Successfully created!")</script>';
    //echo '<script>window.location.href = "/sourcing/index.php"</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is `createdatatry.php`?

Comment: If you're just starting out, avoid learning bad habits. Use PDO and prepared statements, not mysqli and substituting variables directly into SQL.

Comment: oh I typed it wrong, Instead of createdata.php, it's createdatatry.php

Comment: And check for errors from the query.

Comment: What is wrong with my code how come the data is not showing in mysql.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems. Like I said, add error checking.

Comment: Are you getting the "Successfully created" alert?

Comment: yes I am getting the "Successfully alert" after I fill up the php form

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param for how to get mysqli errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Apparently, I did not check the structure of my table (ex. data types) that is why the data is not visible in mysql.

Answer (score -1):

You have given wrong file name in forms action on index.php

You have to write action="createdata.php" in form on index.php

Comment: He already responded to a comment saying that he wrote the wrong filename here.

Comment: it supposed to be createdatatry.php not createdata.php. I typed it wrong in my question

Comment: Please share more details to your answer such that others can learn from it. Wouldn't that throw a pretty obvious 404 error?

Answer (score -1):

Form action should be like this :

form action = "createdata.php" method="POST"

Your query should be like this :

$queryCreate = "INSERT INTO supplierinfo (Supplier_Name, Supplier_Contact, Supplier_StreetNo, Supplier_Province, Supplier_PostalCode, Supplier_Country) VALUES ('$Supplier_name', '$Supplier_Contact', '$Supplier_StreetNo', '$Supplier_Prov', '$Supplier_PostalCode', '$Supplier_Country')";

Comment: i tried this but the data is still not visible in mysql :(

Comment: What do you mean by "like this"? That's still highly vulnerable code that should **never** be used

Answer (score -1):

For your query

```
$queryCreate = "INSERT INTO supplierinfo (`Supplier_Name`, `Supplier_Contact`, `Supplier_StreetNo`, `Supplier_Province`, `Supplier_PostalCode`, `Supplier_Country`) VALUES ('$Supplier_name', '$Supplier_Contact', '$Supplier_StreetNo', '$Supplier_Prov', '$Supplier_PostalCode', '$Supplier_ountry')";
```

```
    $sqlCreate = mysqli_query($connection, $queryCreate);
```

You only assigned mysqli_query($connection, $queryCreate) to a PHP variable , but you didnt execute it.

Try this

```
if(mysqli_query($connection, $queryCreate)){
  echo '<script>alert("Successfully created!")</script>';
}
```

Comment: By all means , this is a nested if else statement in your if(isset) statement.

Comment: I tried this however, what does it mean if "successfully created" is not showing after I fill up the form?

Comment: Then it will be the sql query problem. Does your console show any errors ?

Comment: No it does not show anything, what do you mean by sql query problem is that the "INSERT INTO" part?

Comment: Yes, however i am not familair with mysql so thats all i can help sadly.

Comment: Please try out the solutions from here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Calling `mysqli_query` **will** execute the query